# "Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context"

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, asmx

I get the exception below when invoking he automagically generated async webmethods that i asked about in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075354/legacy-asmx-webservice-how-to-use-automagically-generated-async-method/9075560#9075560)

> Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context. Page starting
>   an asynchronous operation has to have the Async attribute set to true
>   and an asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to

Google search results in add `Async = True` in the page directive but various people have noted that this makes the page **'Blocking'** (which isn't true asynchronous operation). So how do i achieve asynchronous operation while calling webservice methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672237/running-an-asynchronous-operation-triggered-by-an-asp-net-web-page-request).  I won't copy/paste the answers from there but I'll extend the discussion some.

The accepted answer is NOT the correct one.   Since there is no 'EndInvoke' there will be a resource leak every time this method is invoked.  [See this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532722/is-endinvoke-optional-sort-of-optional-or-definitely-not-optional) on why that's not okay.

What is suggested instead is to launch either a daemon thread or create whole different processes that reads from MSMQ and processes the long-running tasks there.